# How to set date parameter in the native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, jira-rest-api

I have created a query like this.

```
String date = "01/01/2021";
String date2  = "01/05/2021"
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * .... From .... Date between ? And ?");
```

I want to set parameters as the two dates in this format "dd/MM/YYYY".

When I tried to set the string dates like this it is giving me an error. Can anyone help me how to do that ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: what is the data type of your date field? is a timestamp or string?

Comment: I am using oracle database, and the data type is timestamp

Comment: `query.setParameter(1, LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")));` should work just fine. Just not 100% sure about `LocalDate` so you might need to fall back on `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string to a `java.util.Date`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer the data is stored in the db in this format : "dd/MM/yyyy" instead

Comment: Then change the pattern of the `DateTimeFormatter`. It was not clear from the question what the correct pattern would be. Also, if the column datatype is timestamp, then you don't need to care about the pattern that might be passed into the query, as it will match what is required by the database

Comment: Is your format of date in your database MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @Asgar no rather dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the strings to LocalDates and then use the relations `<=` and `>=`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE :low <= date AND date <= :high
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.